# RHEL 7.2: Start Hotspot via CLI

Tags: command-line, rhel, wifi-hotspot

GUI approach to start wireless hotspot (that comes with package) is well-known.

How can I start Wireless hotspot (that comes with package) via a CLI in RHEL 7.2?

(There are 3rd party options which are known and documented and have their CLI guides. )

Answer (score 1):

To create and **start** hotspot from the CLI , there are many ways :

**hostapd**

Pre-requisites : install `dnsmasq` and `hostapd` (All linux distro) , under RHEL based distro run:

```
yum install hostapd
yum install dnsmasq
```

Then you need to install `hotspotd`:

```
wget https://github.com/prahladyeri/hotspotd/raw/master/dist/hotspotd-0.1.tar.gz
cd hotspotd-0.1.4
sudo python setup.py install
```

Once done run start `hotspotd`

```
sudo hotspotd start
```

First time you are invited to type your SSID and your Password , next time the command `sudo hotspotd start` will start the saved configuration automatically.

To stop the hotspot run:

```
sudo hotspotd stop
```

**`nmtui`** (Without adding 3rd party tools)

You can configure and **start** the through `nmtui`:

To configure the AP, open the terminal and run : `nmtui`:

Choose **edit connection** then **add** , choose **wifi** scroll down and modify the **Mod** to **Access Point** :

To start the Hotspot run `nmtui` command from the terminal, choose **Activate a connexion** then select  your the SSID of your AP and choose **Activate/Desactivate**.

```
                       ┌─┤ NetworkManager TUI ├──┐                          
                       │                         │                          
                       │ Please select an option │                          
                       │                         │                          
                       │ Edit a connection       │                          
                       │ Activate a connection   │                          
                       │ Set system hostname     │                          
                       │                         │                          
                       │ Quit                    │                          
                       │                         │                          
                       │                    <OK> │                          
                       │                         │                          
                       └─────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: This is about adding a 3rd party tool. Anyway to start wifi hotspot which is in-built inside rhel 7.2 package?

Comment: @GC13 you can run `nmtui` without installing anything